# Connection refused for Docker application on OSX

Tags: python, macos, flask, docker, port

I'm messing about with Docker (using Docker Toolbox for OSX) and can't seem to get my application to work. It's a simple flask application which looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now my Dockerfile contains the following

```
FROM python:2.7.11-wheezy

ADD ./application/* /opt/local/application/
ADD ./project-requirements.txt /opt/local/application/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /opt/local/application/requirements.txt

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/python", "/opt/local/application/app.py"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

I build the container by running `docker build -t python_app .` and subsequently boot the container by running `docker -i -P python_app` and see that the application is booted inside the container, as the output of the command is `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`.

Now when I run `docker ps` I can see the container is running

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
448defb349ce        python_app          "/usr/local/bin/pytho"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:32769->5000/tcp   angry_jang
```

But when I try to curl the container, I get a connection refused error.

```
$ curl $(docker-machine ip default):32769
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 32769: Connection refused
```

I have no clue where I'm going wrong with this and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the issue, I had to change

```
app.run()
```

to

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

in the `app.py` file.